# How can I merge/compose/recombine an A3 image from 3 A4 images?

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-editing, rebuild

That is not the first time that I have following problem.

I must scan an A3 page but my scanner can only scan A4 pages.

So, I scan 3 A4 images as in following example.

[image: left part of image]
[image: middle part of image]
[image: right part of image]

Now, how can I AUTOMATICALLY recombine these 3 images to get original A3 image ?

Can I use ImageMagick to do the job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Hugin](https://hugin.sourceforge.io/)** often does a good job at stitching together images, automatically positioning and rotating them. While mostly a photography tool, it has a specific [tutorial for stitching scans](https://hugin.sourceforge.io/tutorials/scans/en.shtml).

Script I used to use to batch-merge files in the past:

```bash
#!bash

# files=("$@")
files=(scan[123].jpg)

# Create a Hugin project
lens=$(printf ",i%d" ${!files[@]})
pto_gen --projection=0 --fov=10    -o tmp0.pto "${files[@]}"
pto_lensstack --new-lens ${lens#,} -o tmp1.pto tmp0.pto

# Feature detection
cpfind --multirow                  -o tmp2.pto tmp1.pto
cpclean                            -o tmp3.pto tmp2.pto
linefind                           -o tmp4.pto tmp3.pto

# Reposition images to match features
pto_var --opt r,d,e,!r0,!d0,!e0    -o tmp5.pto tmp4.pto
autooptimiser -n                   -o tmp6.pto tmp5.pto

# Stitch images
pano_modify --projection=0 --fov=AUTO --center --canvas=AUTO --crop=AUTO \
                                   -o tmp7.pto tmp6.pto
hugin_executor -s --prefix="stitched"          tmp7.pto
```

Output of the script (not as rectangular as it could be, but readable – you can open one of the `.pto` project files in Hugin GUI to tweak and re-render it):

[image]

Comment: great job ! Thanks

Comment: I have tested your script on WSL and with some adaptation I have generated a TIFF file.
First of all, in your script "--stiching" parameter must be replaced by "--stitching" with last version of Hugin. Can you correct your answer ? Thanks
How can I generate a JPG file instead of a TIF file ?

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need to generate a TIFF first and convert it to JPEG afterwards (e.g. using ImageMagick).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested **user1686** answer using pure DOS.

The tested DOS solution that works on my PC on Windows 10 is following.

```
::************************************************************
::* MERGES-3-FILES.bat
::************************************************************

SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin;%PATH%

::*-----------------------------------------------------------
::* Create a Hugin project
::*-----------------------------------------------------------

pto_gen.exe --projection=0 --fov=10    -o tmp0.pto Left.jpg Mid.jpg Right.jpg
pto_lensstack.exe --new-lens i0,i1,i2  -o tmp1.pto tmp0.pto

::*-----------------------------------------------------------
::* Feature's detection
::*-----------------------------------------------------------

cpfind.exe --multirow                  -o tmp2.pto tmp1.pto
cpclean.exe                            -o tmp3.pto tmp2.pto
linefind.exe                           -o tmp4.pto tmp3.pto

::*-----------------------------------------------------------
::* Reposition images to match features
::*-----------------------------------------------------------

pto_var.exe --opt r,d,e,!r0,!d0,!e0    -o tmp5.pto tmp4.pto
autooptimiser.exe -n                   -o tmp6.pto tmp5.pto

::*-----------------------------------------------------------
:: Stitch images
::*-----------------------------------------------------------

pano_modify.exe --projection=0 --fov=AUTO --center --canvas=AUTO --crop=AUTO -o tmp7.pto tmp6.pto
hugin_executor.exe --stitching --prefix="stitched" tmp7.pto

::*-----------------------------------------------------------
:: Delete intermediate files
::*-----------------------------------------------------------

del /Q *.pto
```